# How do I merge two linked lists in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I asked a question last night on how to `sort()` a double linked list in C++.
I managed to get it to work, but now I'd like to merge two lists, but I can't
get it to work. I don't have much code, I'm sorry. Everything I tried
absolutely made no sense. I'd just like if someone could give me some hints on
where to start, or on how to do this, with the information I'm going to
provide.

This is what I had in the beginning:

```
void next() { if (curr != tail) curr = curr->next; }
```

I believe I only need these.

I looked at some exemples online, but it doesn't make any sense to me. It
seems so different than what I have right now. Apparently it should be A LOT
easier than doing a sort function, which I had barely any trouble doing.

Any explanation/hints would be greatly appreciated! And I'm sorry once again
for the lack of code, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: "Everything I tried absolutely made no sense." - perhaps you should try something that makes sense.

Comment: If I have the following: List<E> list1, list2. list1.merge(list2); is list 2 changed, which one is the merged list? We have 2 objects here. Please be specific with preconditions and postconditions.

Comment: I'm just saying, you should first figure out how you do it... If you have two linked lists on paper (with pencil), can you merge them? Just observe the steps you're doing.

Comment: @Exn, I'm going to have to agree with the others. I suspect that your problem is that you don't have a deep understanding of linked lists. Without that knowledge, answers to questions like these will only make you more confused.

Comment: Maybe we should back up a bit: what are you really trying to accomplish? Do you want to splice one list to the end of the other, or do you want to take two sorted lists, and merge them to one sorted list (or something else entirely)?

Comment: for each(auto x in list2namehere){list1namehere.push_back(x);} //?? =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this in multiple ways

1. Take the two sorted lists, and literally merge them so that you end up with a sorted list
2. Take the two sorted lists, and create a third new list that contains elements from both the lists in sorted order
3. Merge the two sorted/unsorted lists, and then sort the resulting list

It looks like you're trying to do no. 3 here.

In which case, you can just

1. Start from head of the current list, and go to next until you reach the last element
2. Set curr->next = other_list.head
3. Call sort on the current list

This would however destruct the original list. I think it's better to copy them to a third list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for_each(auto x in list2name)
{
list1name.push_back(x);
}
```

or if you're using `C++ 11`

```
for(auto x : list2name)
{
list1name.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: `for_each(auto x in list2name)` How does that work in C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the std::list as a linked list you can always use the existing merge() function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/

If this is something you have implemented yourself just get the tail of one of the lists and use something like this:

```
   tail = list_1.get_tail();
   tail.set_next(list_2.get_head())
```

Basically getting the last entry in list 1 and then setting the next elemt to be the first element of list 2.

I'm still a bit confused what you're after, but this is the most basic way I can think of.
Then again, I might be completely off.
Good luck